# Change image when pressing uiimageview

Tags: uiimageview, imageview

i am doing a very simpel memory game to a ipad.
I want to change the image on the uiimageview when pressing it, and change it back when pressing it again.
Thanks for any help!
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Tap gesture recognizer to change the imageview's image.I upload my code for tap gesture on image.
**Note : Don't forget to imageview's UserInteraction is enable.**
The below code write in your ViewDidLoad method.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *firstdoubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(firstTapGesture:)];
firstdoubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[_firstimageview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[_firstimageview addGestureRecognizer:firstdoubleTap];
```

Than Your action method.

```
- (void)firstTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
     _firstimageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"abcd.png"];
}
```